# Iterating over a list of dictionaries for an entire column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, nested-lists, nested-for-loop

I have column with rows that look like the following:

```
[]
[{'id': 'EQ01', 'siteName': 'WW INSTR FG'}]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[{'id': 'RM00', 'siteName': 'WW RAW MATERIAL'}]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[{'id': 'PR03', 'siteName': 'INST PROD'}, {'id': 'RM00', 'siteName': 'WW RAW MATERIAL'}, {'id': 'RM03', 'siteName': 'INST MATERIAL'}]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[{'id': 'PR05', 'siteName': 'MEQ PROD'}]
```

I'm trying to get the value for the key 'id' for the first dictionary in the list of dictionaries for each row, then assign that value to a new column called 'location' at the given index.

```
rowIndex = -1
for lists in df_elem['sites']:
    rowIndex +=1 
    for dicts in lists:
        locations = dicts.get('id')
        print(locations)
        df_elem.loc[rowIndex, 'locations'] = locations
```

This code seemed to work for other columns just fine (and fast enough) but for whatever reason I'm getting a type error: float object not iterable. Which is weird because I can print each value after it's assigned to the location variable, but I can't assign that value or append it to a list(after many approaches). What am I missing here? How should I code this? I know there are methods like below but I'd rater not use them. I'm trying to improve my functional programing skills.

```
df.explode('column')
```

Comment: For me your code runs fine with the example you provided.

Comment: I have no idea what was going on before, but your right it seems to be working! Thanks for verifying for me. haha